# Mediaplayer overlaps when the button is pressed several times

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I am making an app in Android Studio using MediaPlayer to use my audio clips, when I press a button, the audio plays correctly, when I press another one, the previous one stops and the new one starts, but if I press repeatedly the same button it starts to overlap, and when I hit the "back" button, only one of the audios stops while the others are still playing.

How could I do to avoid that, when pressing a button several times, it overlaps, and instead it "restarts" without overlapping.

Thank you!

Here´s my Java Code

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import com.denzcoskun.imageslider.ImageSlider;
import com.denzcoskun.imageslider.models.SlideModel;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

public class Infomezquita extends AppCompatActivity {
    private MediaPlayer AZASOUND;
    private MediaPlayer AZASOUNDUK;
    private MediaPlayer AZARAB;
    private MediaPlayer AZAFRENCH;
    private MediaPlayer AZAGER;
    private MediaPlayer AZAIT;
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mezquita);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Mosque");


        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {

            if (AZASOUNDUK != null && AZASOUNDUK.isPlaying()) {
                AZASOUNDUK.stop(); // or mp.pause();
                AZASOUNDUK.release();
            }
            if(AZASOUND != null && AZASOUND.isPlaying()) {
                AZASOUND.stop();
                //AZASOUND.release();
            }
            if(AZARAB != null && AZARAB.isPlaying()) {
                AZARAB.stop();
                //AZASOUND.release();
            }
            if(AZAFRENCH != null && AZAFRENCH.isPlaying()) {
                AZAFRENCH.stop();
                //AZASOUND.release();
            }
            if(AZAGER != null && AZAGER.isPlaying()) {
                AZAGER.stop();
                //AZASOUND.release();
            }
            if(AZAIT != null && AZAIT.isPlaying()) {
                AZAIT.stop();
                //AZASOUND.release();
            }
            else {
                finish();
            }
            super.onBackPressed();
        }


        @Override
        protected void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
            if (handler != null)
                handler.removeCallbacks(null);
        }

        public void SONIDO (View view)
        {
            AZASOUND = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.mezquitaes);
            AZASOUND.start();

            if(AZASOUNDUK != null && AZASOUNDUK.isPlaying())
            {
                //AZASOUNDUK.pause();
                //AZASOUNDUK.pause();
                AZASOUNDUK.stop();
            }
            if(AZAFRENCH != null && AZAFRENCH.isPlaying())
            {
                //AZASOUNDUK.pause();
                AZAFRENCH.stop();
            }
            if(AZAGER != null && AZAGER.isPlaying())
            {
                //AZASOUNDUK.pause();
                AZAGER.stop();
            }
            if(AZAIT != null && AZAIT.isPlaying())
            {
                //AZASOUNDUK.pause();
                AZAIT.stop();
            }
            else if(AZARAB != null && AZARAB.isPlaying())
            {
                //AZASOUNDUK.pause();
                AZARAB.stop();
            }
            super.onStop();
        }

        public void SONIDOUK (View view) {
            AZASOUNDUK = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.mezquitauk);
            AZASOUNDUK.start();

            if(AZASOUND != null && AZASOUND.isPlaying())
            {
                //AZASOUNDUK.pause();
                AZASOUND.stop();
            }
            if(AZAFRENCH != null && AZAFRENCH.isPlaying())
            {
                //AZASOUNDUK.pause();
                AZAFRENCH.stop();
            }
            if(AZAGER != null && AZAGER.isPlaying())
            {
                //AZASOUNDUK.pause();
                AZAGER.stop();
            }
            if(AZAIT != null && AZAIT.isPlaying())
            {
                //AZASOUNDUK.pause();
                AZAIT.stop();
            }
            else if(AZARAB != null && AZARAB.isPlaying())
            {
                //AZASOUNDUK.pause();
                AZARAB.stop();
            }
            super.onPause();
        }

        public void SONIDOARAB (View view) {
            AZARAB = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.mezquitaarab);
            AZARAB.start();
            Toast.makeText(Infomezquita.this, "ارفع الصوت", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //OK
            if(AZASOUND != null && AZASOUND.isPlaying())
            {
                //AZASOUNDUK.pause();
                AZASOUND.stop();
            }
            if(AZASOUNDUK != null && AZASOUNDUK.isPlaying())
            {
                //AZASOUNDUK.pause();
                AZASOUNDUK.stop();
            }
            if(AZAGER != null && AZAGER.isPlaying())
            {
                //AZASOUNDUK.pause();
                AZAGER.stop();
            }
            if(AZAIT != null && AZAIT.isPlaying())
            {
                //AZASOUNDUK.pause();
                AZAIT.stop();
            }
            else if(AZAFRENCH != null && AZAFRENCH.isPlaying())
            {
                //AZASOUNDUK.pause();
                AZAFRENCH.stop();
            }

            super.onPause();
        }

        public void SONIDOGER (View view) {
            AZAGER = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.mezquitager);
            AZAGER.start();
            if(AZASOUND != null && AZASOUND.isPlaying())
            {
                //AZASOUNDUK.pause();
                AZASOUND.stop();
            }
            if(AZASOUNDUK != null && AZASOUNDUK.isPlaying())
            {
                //AZASOUNDUK.pause();
                AZASOUNDUK.stop();
            }
            if(AZAFRENCH != null && AZAFRENCH.isPlaying())
            {
                //AZASOUNDUK.pause();
                AZAFRENCH.stop();
            }
            if(AZAIT != null && AZAIT.isPlaying())
            {
                //AZASOUNDUK.pause();
                AZAIT.stop();
            }
            else if(AZARAB != null && AZARAB.isPlaying())
            {
                //AZASOUNDUK.pause();
                AZARAB.stop();
            }

            super.onPause();
        }

        public void SONIDOFRENCH (View view) {
            AZAFRENCH = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.mezquitafr);
            AZAFRENCH.start();
            if(AZASOUNDUK != null && AZASOUNDUK.isPlaying())
            {
                //AZASOUNDUK.pause();
                AZASOUNDUK.stop();
            }
            if(AZASOUND != null && AZASOUND.isPlaying())
            {
                //AZASOUNDUK.pause();
                AZASOUND.stop();
            }
            if(AZAGER != null && AZAGER.isPlaying())
            {
                //AZASOUNDUK.pause();
                AZAGER.stop();
            }
            if(AZAIT != null && AZAIT.isPlaying())
            {
                //AZASOUNDUK.pause();
                AZAIT.stop();
            }
            else if(AZARAB != null && AZARAB.isPlaying())
            {
                //AZASOUNDUK.pause();
                AZARAB.stop();
            }

            super.onPause();
        }

        public void SONIDOITA (View view) {
            AZAIT = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.mezquitait);
            AZAIT.start();
            if(AZASOUNDUK != null && AZASOUNDUK.isPlaying())
            {
                //AZASOUNDUK.pause();
                AZASOUNDUK.stop();
            }
            if(AZASOUND != null && AZASOUND.isPlaying())
            {
                //AZASOUNDUK.pause();
                AZASOUND.stop();
            }
            if(AZAGER != null && AZAGER.isPlaying())
            {
                //AZASOUNDUK.pause();
                AZAGER.stop();
            }
            if(AZAFRENCH != null && AZAFRENCH.isPlaying())
            {
                //AZASOUNDUK.pause();
                AZAFRENCH.stop();
            }
            else if(AZARAB != null && AZARAB.isPlaying())
            {
                //AZASOUNDUK.pause();
                AZARAB.stop();
            }

            super.onPause();
        }

    public void MAPA(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MapaROMANO.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    public void FOTOS(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SliderMain.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void ROM2(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SliderMain.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void MAPAMEZCA(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Mapa1.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void URLMEZCA (View view) {
        Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse("example");
        Intent launchBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);
        startActivity(launchBrowser);
    }
}


  [1]: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BlUql0PqSgQ
```

Comment: Why are you using a lot of MediaPlayer rather than one player?

Comment: @ShohanAhmedSijan Every mp has one audio file, if you can help me to make it more efficiently i´ll be gratefull. PD. SoundPool is not an option because every audio has at least 2 minutes

Comment: Ok answering...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a lot of MediaPlayer creations without any release. Please check the below code, it may help you to identify the right way.

```
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
public void play(int rawSoundId){
    stop();
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, rawSoundId);
    mediaPlayer.start();
}

public void pause() {
    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
        mediaPlayer.pause();
    }
}

public void stop() {
    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
        }
        mediaPlayer.release();
        mediaPlayer = null;
    }
}
```

Just call **play(R.raw.mezquitait)** from your view functions.

Comment: Just working! Finally I can fixed it, thanks a lot mate!